# In Chrome, how to know if "access-control-expose-headers" header is present?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cors

I would like to know a way to find out if `access-control-expose-headers` is present, only using plain Javascript.

Use case is: I have a demo app in JS where you can select several servers, and testing servers return some debug info, and the demo would like to show the debug info if it's available. But trying to read `access-control-expose-headers` header to see if I can read the exposed headers in Chrome causes a console error. Chicken-egg problem?

Comment: What error does it log?

Comment: If `access-control-expose-headers` does not expose itself (i.e., `"access-control-expose-headers"` is not in the value), you can't get its value from JavaScript.

Comment: Error is: "Refused to get unsafe header `access-control-expose-headers`". I'm not interested in the value, I just want to know if it's there. And if it's not there, somehow to catch the error so the console does not show it.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the code that tries to read them in an exception handler.

```js
const url = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://example.com";
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", url);
xhr.addEventListener("load", () => {
  let header;
  try {
    header = xhr.getResponseHeader('access-control-expose-headers');
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("There was an error: ", e);
  }

  if (header) {
    console.log("Header successfully read", header);
  } else {
    console.log("Could not read header or header does not exist");
  }
});
xhr.send();
```

Comment: This code does not work. The code should return: `There was an error: Refused to get unsafe header access-control-expose-headers` (your code), but instead it returns: `Refused to get unsafe header "access-control-expose-headers` (Chrome error)
In other words, it does not go through the `catch`